# How do I pair apple wireless keyboard with windows 10

Tags: keyboard, wifi, windows, bluetooth

My apple wireless keyboard has stopped pairing with Windows 10. Now when I try to pair through settings, I'm asked to enter a passcode for the keyboard rather than being supplied a passcode to pair the device. I'm unable to type anything using the keyboard. Entering four zeros using the laptop keyboard does not work. I've tried un-installing bluetooth drivers and reinstalling. This doesn't help. Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the Boot Camp drivers?

Comment: Windows 10 is installed on my PC not a Mac

Comment: All solutions given below didn't work for me. To fix this, you need to delete a registry key under this address 

Computer\HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Bluetooth\ExceptionDB\Addrs


 - After deletion, try to add keyboard again and it will show the pin code which you will have to type on the Apple keyboard. This works like a charm.

Answer (score 44):

After trying 15 times in vain, here is the method that worked for me (source)

1. Go to "Add Bluetooth or other device"
2. Find the wireless keyboard and click on it.
3. When prompted for a pin, enter any 6 digits on the computer's internal keyboard and press CONNECT.
4. While it says connecting, enter same 6 digits on the external keyboard and press enter. It should successfully connect.
5. Repeat until successful.

Comment: As ridiculous as the answer sounds it works in some cases ~ at least in mine. I was in limbo, and was prompted for a PIN without seeing what it was. I read about using 1234 and I tried it but it never worked. The steps here are a touch unbelievable however I followed them, instead used 1234. After a few times getting the timing correct, it worked. Good job persevering and sharing to those of us who are stuck.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me.

Comment: On the old "magic keyboard", additional thing to keep in mind is pressing the "on" button all the time while doing the manipulations above. So, it's best to use a helping of additional person while setting up the device.

Comment: For #3/4/5, it's not a timing thing, you'll have ample time to enter the code you chose to pair with on your bluetooth keyboard, but I didn't realize you had to enter it twice (once on my existing/wired keyboard to tell Windows to accept a pairing code, and AGAIN on the Apple keyboard to confirm/pair).

Comment: Wow, this worked for me, thanks! (I'm typing with my apple keyboard on windows)

Comment: This worked immediately, thank you for figuring this out and sharing.

Comment: Just typing this from connected "magic keyboard". Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

I know this thread is old but this worked for me... currently typing on my (1st-gen) Apple Wireless Keyboard, Lenovo X1 Tablet (3rd-gen - "Clamshell" mode), Windows 10 Pro 1809:

1 - I'm sure you can use Bluetooth in the Settings app, but I used Control Panel. I searched for "bluetooth" and clicked "Add a Bluetooth device" under "Devices and Printers."

2 - I powered the Apple Wireless Keyboard **OFF** (if already off then proceed..)

3 - I held down the power button on the keyboard until the green LED came on AND started flashing... **KEEP HOLDING THROUGHOUT PAIRING PROCESS!**

4 - The pairing code FINALLY came up, and I was able to type in the code/hit enter (while still holding the power button on the keyboard).

5 - I let off of the power button upon pairing finalized, the computer installed drivers, and I typed this response!

Thanks and good luck,

Your friendly neighborhood Brando

Comment: Nice one! While adding the keyboard from control panel, it actually showed up a button called "try inputting code from keyboard", which then gave me a code to input on the keyboard again.

Comment: I applied this technique with the one of Rohan: I kept the pushing the power button while I entered 1234 enter (on another keyboard) then (not too fast! maybe a second later) 1234 enter (on the problematic apple wireless keyboard) then it worked!

Comment: Started from windows control panel, and than needed to press the Power button at BT keyboard and the pairing initialization number, and is not working the 123123 + ENTEr

Answer (score 9):

Currently using Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad (A1843) with Windows 10

1. In Windows 10's bluetooth settings (can be found in system tray), click on the icon and then click "Add Bluetooth Device".
2. On the Apple Wireless Keyboard, turn it on and hold down `Command + W`, while Windows is searching for bluetooth devices.
3. After your keyboard appears in the list of found devices, click on it and then follow the screen prompts and eventually you will have to type in a pairing code. Type any code and hit return.

Your Keyboard should successfully pair with Windows 10 via the Mac's Bluetooth

Edit:

- You need to unpair the keyboard if you have connected to your MAC or other device
- You can use a lightning cable if you don't have another keyboard available, after pairing you can remove the cable

Comment: The KILLER item here (sorry should have be more POSITIVE!) is holding down CMD/W. It worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Nic is right! If after the pairing step you don't get asked for a PIN, reread this point: "You need to unpair the keyboard if you have connected to your MAC or another device"

Answer (score 2):

How to pair an Apple wireless keyboard on Windows 10:

1. Go into your Bluetooth settings, scroll down and click on "Devices and printers" under the "Related settings" header
2. Click on "add a device" at this stage make sure the keyboard is in pairing mode (the green light on the keyboard should be flashing"
3. When Windows finds your keyboard, double click on it
4. It will ask you for a pin but if you don't already have one under the box where the pin goes click "Try entering passcode on it" (Windows will then generate a passcode for you)
5. Then type the passcode out using your Apple Wireless keyboard and press Enter
6. Your keyboard should be all set up

Comment: This solution has worked for me. When paring through the Windows Settings window, it asks you a code that you don't know. If you pair the keyboard through the Control Panel, It has the option to "Try entering passcode on it" (just like Pete said). [I am using Windows 10 1909 in a Lenovo P53 and connecting to Apple Wireless keyboard model A1314]

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem as well. I fixed it by going to bluetooth settings in control panel instead of action center.

1. Press the windows key on your old keyboard and type in "Control Panel"
2. In the searchbar type in bluetooth
3. Select "add a bluetooth device"
4. Make sure your keyboard is turned on and in pairing mode (flashing green light)
5. Then select it and type in the passcode listed on the screen using your new keyboard, and press enter. 
   Note: the screen doesn't give information about what key was already typed, so this may take a few tries if your press the wrong key.

Comment: One step left out. Press the link below the form field to reveal the passcode.

Comment: This did not work for me. I am pressing the pin but the "press connect if the PIN on Magic Keyboard with numeric keypad matches this one" I am pressing the pin on the keyboard but it is not working at all

Answer (score 1):

With the new Apple Wireless Keyboards and Touch Pads you need first to connect device to the PC via USB-to-USC-C cable. After that when you go to the Bluetooth section on Windows 10 you will see that keyboard and will be able to pair it.