# How do you connect an Apple Magic Keyboard with Numeric pad to Windows 10 via Bluetooth?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I recently bought an Apple magic keyboard with numeric pad to use with my computer, after reading threads online that you can connect it via Bluetooth to a Windows PC. When I search to add a new Bluetooth device, my PC doesn't find the keyboard.

I tested the keyboard with my MacBook Pro where I am able to use it fine. It also connects using the wire to my PC, but it won't find the keyboard via Bluetooth. My Windows PC has Bluetooth 5.0, and I've tried holding down <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, tried resetting the keyboard via my MacBook Pro, but it still isn't able to find my keyboard.

Does anyone know a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Is your Windows PC able to detect and pair with other Bluetooth devices?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Thanks :). Yeah my PC is able to detect other devices and I've connected my phone to my PC too as a test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pair apple wireless keyboard with windows 10](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227546/how-do-i-pair-apple-wireless-keyboard-with-windows-10)

Comment: @NimeshNeema I have looked at this, but it didn't work for me. The keyboard was still not detected by bluetooth when searching to add new devices.

Comment: @RyanHolland - these directions seem to imply that you may have to do it a couple tries to get it to work - https://pupungbp.com/how-to-pair-apple-wireless-keyboard-with-windows-10/.

Answer (score 4):

When you have the Windows Bluetooth pane open and it is searching for devices then slide the power control on the keyboard to Off and then On shortly after. This should make the keyboard discoverable by Windows.

Make sure that the keyboard is not plugged in via cable to another computer, and make sure that it is not able to communicate with a previously paired Mac at the same time.

Note that the comments you have received earlier regarding duplicates and directions concerns a completely different keyboard, namely the "Apple Wireless Keyboard". You have the "Apple Magic Keyboard" which works in a slightly different manner regarding Bluetooth pairing - and it doesn't have a power button, but rather a slider.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I also tried to connect the Apple Magic Keyboard to Windows 10 and I ran into several problems.

1. As long as I had it connected via USB, it couldn't be discovered by
   Windows
2. Even when pairing was then initialized, Windows showed a driver
   problem

So I unplugged the keyboard and installed Magic Utilities.

https://magicutilities.net/magic-keyboard/download

Once they were installed, the pairing worked fine - no driver issues any more. I didn't have to enter any sort of PIN on the keyboard - as mentioned elsewhere on the web -, but simply confirmed that this was the right device.

I am writing this via bluetooth now! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can map all of the fn keys and more to their functions(e.g. F11 for VolumeDown) through this github package that I have submitted a [PR for to add installation instructions](https://github.com/uxsoft/AppleWirelessKeyboard/compare/master...DCastaban:patch-1).

I haven't been able to connect to my keyboard through bluetooth, although it does show up in the pairing section, it just doesn't let me connect.

Comment: How does this answer the question asked?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/312046)