# Opt out of the code entry when connecting BT keyboard (macOS 13.4)

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

After buying a new (14-in M2) MBP I cannot connect my bluetooth keyboard to it. I think the reason is that it doesn't support entry while still connecting (it's Zoom65, so a pretty niche keyboard). Back on my old 16-in i9 MBP the problem doesn't exist since it doesn't ask for the code (macOS 12.5).
Is there any way of disabling this code-entry on keyboard connection on the new macOS?

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/227546/489896

Comment: [That method is still supported under Ventura](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/connect-a-bluetooth-device-blth1004).  Per Zoom’s website, it’s BT 5.  Entering the “code” is not a security thing, but an [identification method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/287013/119271).  Trying connecting the keyboard via the USB cable first, then pair it with BT.

Comment: Thank you @Allan, this solved my problem! I first connected the keyboard using USB, and after that the bluetooth connection wizard didn't ask me for the code anymore.

Comment: Go ahead and write up an answer and ping me in comments again so I can upvote.  Oh, and Welcome to Ask Different!